# Does the [L] flag ignore the following code

Tags: .htaccess, flags

Just a simple question. In a -htaccess file, I can set a [L] flag. Does this "L" only ignore if rewrite stuff come after or the complete code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

In other words, are the lines after the L-flag considered or is it better to put in always on last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [L] flag causes **mod_rewrite** to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

So, in your case, the following instructions are not affected.